# Creating a pocket mediaserver using Raspberry Pi that can let you stream files

Tags: media, hub

I'm attempting to turn my Raspberry Pi into a media passport. that can let me stream files from the Raspbery Pi onto other devices.

The things I need for this project are:

- Media software on the Raspberry Pi
- Client-side software on my computer or phone
- A way to stream wirelessly (bluetooth, wifi, etc.)

Finally what programming language would be good to use for this?

Comment: I made some edits to make this question clearer--if you need any other information feel free to update it.

Comment: thanks for that I updated it , i was confused about what launguage to use for the programming i only know c and matlab at the moment but im willing to learn something else aswell.

Comment: Generally speaking, "What language should I use" is a tough nut to crack since it boils down to opinions and discussion.  If you're asking how to install a media server on Raspberry Pi, then the question fits here.  If you're asking *how to program a media server*, your question might belong elsewhere.  Try to pick *one goal* per question you ask.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
Install Minidlna to stream media from the Raspberry Pi.
Use a Wifi dongle to create a hotspot
Then all you need is power to be able to stream media from the Pi via the hotspot to a device which connects via wifi.

MiniDLNA is a DLNA server designed to stream media from a central repository to DLNA clients. This means that any device that can run a DLNA capable media player will be able to view video from the Pi, TVs, Laptops, Mobile Phones, etc.
VLC can be used from a PC/Laptop
I use [Skifta](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.skifta.android.app&hl=en) on my Android mobile, but I'm not sure what players iOS have.

Running a hotspot from the Pi will allow wifi access to the DLNA server without having to setup a separate device to allow access over wifi. Using a RT5370 device would be the easiest IMO as it's plug and play when it comes to hot spots.
Simply install hostapd and dnsmasq, configure hostapd to your needs, and configure dnsmasq with these 2 lines -
`interface=wlan0`
`dhcp-range=10.0.0.2,10.0.0.10,255.255.255.0,12h`
and then set a static IP address of 10.0.0.1 on wlan0, and away you go.

Comment: what is the stream rate with minidlna and are there any other wireless alternatives?

Comment: Look up DLNA for alternatives. Stream rate depends on the file being streamed.